# PHP : Parse ini file with .php extension

Tags: php, regex, ini

How can i parse ini file with .php extension. eg **config.ini.php**
below are content file as in it.

```
<?php
[Session]
SessionTimeout=1200
ActivityTimeout=600
CookieTimeout=0
SessionNameHandler=custom
Handler=SessionHandlerDB
?>
```

I tried **parse_ini_file** its not working.

here is the error i am getting **Warning: syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '='**

I am using a framework in which I cannot remove PHP tag.

Comment: Remove the php tags

Comment: i cannot do that. its part of cms. we are using it in other section.

Comment: You must. It's not valid PHP code. You can only put valid PHP code inside PHP tags. And the tags are not valid INI syntax.

Comment: At the very least you need to indicate what you mean by "its not working". Is there an error, does it not load data, return a bad value?

Comment: @SunilSilumala If you cannot remove the `<?php` and `?>` can you at least prepend them with semicolons? This will allow it to validate as a well-formed INI file. If not you'll need to write a method to read the file, strip the tags, and then parse it as an INI.

Comment: If you cannot remove the `<?php` and `?>` then something is *very wrong* in your project.  Why would you be saving a file as `config.ini.php` when it cannot be loaded as a PHP file?  It's not PHP code, so `<?php` and `?>` are *wrong*.

Comment: The only other solution is to read in the file with `file_get_contents`, remove the PHP tags (using `str_replace` or similar) then using `parse_ini_string()`.

Comment: We need a red line, but it's got to be blue because we use it elsewhere...

Comment: Are you writing your own CMS, or is this an open source CMS?

Comment: I am using ezpublish cms

Comment: @JonStirling I need seven red lines, all perpendicular please

Comment: @jszobody And one with transparent ink.

Comment: @JonStirling And make the green ones thicker, thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$configContent = file_get_contents('config.ini.php');
$iniContent = preg_replace('/<\?php|\?>/m', '', $configContent);
var_export(parse_ini_string($iniContent));
```

Result:

```
array (
  'SessionTimeout' => '1200',
  'ActivityTimeout' => '600',
  'CookieTimeout' => '0',
  'SessionNameHandler' => 'custom',
  'Handler' => 'SessionHandlerDB',
)
```

Comment: Upvote for the creative solution. Though I strongly urge the OP to rethink their whole approach.

Comment: Yes, i agree that approach is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you cannot remove the PHP-tags, a better approach:

```
<?php
return [
    'session' => [
        'SessionTimeout'     => 1200,
        'ActivityTimeout'    => 600,
        'CookieTimeout'      => 0,
        'SessionNameHandler' => 'custom',
        'Handler'            => 'SessionHandlerDB',
    ]
];
```

Use:

```
$config = require 'config.inc.php';
```

Comment: I wonder *why* the OP can't remove the PHP tags.  If he can't do that, can he even edit the file at all?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is more than 5 years old now, but I wanted to add my 2¢.

I don't know why everyone is giving the OP such a hard time about creating their ini file as PHP. It adds extra security so that even if a user knows the path to the file, it cannot be accessed.

To answer the OP's original question, I'm doing this in my own homebrewed CMS and it's working beautifully with `parse_ini_file`:

```
;<?php die();
/*
[Session]
SessionTimeout=1200
ActivityTimeout=600
CookieTimeout=0
SessionNameHandler=custom
Handler=SessionHandlerDB
*/
?>
```

Just block comment out the ini code and prepend the first line with a semi-colon. The ini sees the PHP as a comment and the PHP sees the ini as a comment, all while `parse_ini_file` can still read it. For even extra security, you can add the `die();`.